# Validate URL with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a URL field that can be all kind of web URL's.

Is there one Zend framework validation classes that can help me like Zend_Validate_EmailAddress does for email ?

Thanks

Comment: Let's see what google says...  http://blog.motane.lu/2012/04/16/validate-urls-in-zend-framework/

Comment: Also http://www.rondobley.com/2011/09/24/how-to-validate-a-url-with-a-scheme-and-hostname-in-zend-framework/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [Zend\Validator\Uri](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.uri.html#zend-validator-uri). You can also use [Zend\Form\Element\Url](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#url) which uses URI Validator

Comment: It seems to be gone without any replacement? Any ideas why and what to use instead?

Comment: Nevermind, it's still there it's just missing from the documentation for some reason!

Answer (score 4):

Adrian's answer is correct, but if you are lazy like me and just want to copy/paste

From: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.uri.chapter.html

```
// Contains '|' symbol
// Normally, this would return false:
$valid = Zend_Uri::check('http://example.com/?q=this|that');

// However, you can allow "unwise" characters
Zend_Uri::setConfig(array('allow_unwise' => true));

// will return 'true'
$valid = Zend_Uri::check('http://example.com/?q=this|that');

// Reset the 'allow_unwise' value to the default FALSE
Zend_Uri::setConfig(array('allow_unwise' => false));
```

> By default, Zend_Uri will not accept the following characters: "{",
>   "}", "|", "\", "^", "`". These characters are defined by the RFC as
>   "unwise" and invalid; however, many implementations do accept these
>   characters as valid.